# What are Garibaldi's other favourite things in the universe?

Tags: babylon-5

In the season two episode "A Spider in the Web,", Garibaldi mentions to Talia that "tea just happens to be [his] third favourite thing in the universe."

Do we ever learn what his first two favourite things are in the universe?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Midnight in the Firing Line, we learn that Daffy Duck Cartoons are his **second** favorite thing

> Afterward, if you like, you can stop by my quarters and I can show you
>   my favorite thing in the universe.
>
> Okay, okay, my second favorite thing in the universe.

The implication being that having sex is his absolute favourite thing.

---

On the excellent [Midwinter site](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/028.html), JMS points out that Garibaldi's third favourite thing is *whatever* the woman is having, essentially that he's just using it as a pickup line:

> Basically, Garibaldi's third favorite thing...is **whatever the member
>   of the opposite sex is having....**

Comment: I would say his favorite thing is Lise. Or maybe you got that one right.

Comment: @Omegacron - Given that he's hitting on Talia, I don't think his mind is on Lise at that precise moment.

Comment: Good point. Of course, as we discover later, boy is he marching up the wrong battlefield.

Comment: @Omegacron - My understanding is that her character was not portrayed as *exclusively* lesbian. Talia had two serious relationships before she met Ivanova, both with men.

Comment: @Richard Although one of those relationships seemed to be pretty against her will.

Comment: @Kai - There's no special indication that she's unhappy with him personally, just that she feels roped into it by PsiCorp.

Comment: @Richard So...the fact that she quickly divorced him doesn't say she was unhappy with him personally?  Besides the fact that an arranged marriage to breed more telepaths doesn't really in my mind constitute as evidence that she's not exclusively a lesbian.  But, of course, her relationship with Ironheart does seems to back up that part.

Comment: @Kai - Historically, a lot of people in arranged marriages have been quite unhappy with the choice of partner.

Comment: @Richard --- perhaps you could omit the word 'arranged' there.

Answer (score 0):

Might it be the Kawasaki Ninja he was building? http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Motorcycle

Comment: I think you'll find that it's Lennier who's the monk...

Answer (score -1):

I believe his favorite thing in the universe is his father's recipe for pasta. But I'm digging into my brain bank from 20 years ago, so not positive...

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. I recommend a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to write the sort of answers we are looking for.